# DirectMusic problems on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, directx

I'm trying to get some DirectX information from the DirectX Diagnostic Tool (dxdiag) and am having a major issue with it.

The first time I loaded it, it never loaded and silently crashed. The second time I loaded it, it gave me an error, "DxDiag has detected that there may have been a problem accessing DirectSound the last time this program was used. Would you like to bypass DirectSound this time?" If I click No, it crashes. If I click Yes, it loads the program.

Now, when I go into any of the tabs (`Display`, `Music`, `Input` for example), it gets stuck on "Loading DirectMusic information".

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&displaylang=en) installer and report results. It should install newest version of DirectX and fix any errors it detects.

If it doesn't help, download and install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3B170B25-ABAB-4BC3-AE91-50CEB6D8FA8D&displayLang=en). It's the newest version of DirectX End-User Runtimes.